# SonarQube extension failure at complete step

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I've trying to setup a sonarqube server and the SonarQube Extension for TFS-VSTS. The server is running fine.

So for the tfs extension I've created a continuous integration build definition and added the extension steps.

[image]

But the result is that each build is failing with the same error:

```
2017-10-13T16:19:29.5062715Z INFO: Analysis report generated in 11485ms, dir size=24 MB
2017-10-13T16:19:40.6625181Z INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 11140ms, zip size=8 MB
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: Total time: 1:01.328s
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: Final Memory: 48M/134M
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z ##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z ##[error]ERROR: Failed to upload report - 500: An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z ##[error]ERROR:
2017-10-13T16:19:44.2718958Z ##[error]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2017-10-13T16:19:44.3969783Z ##[error]The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
2017-10-13T16:19:44.3969783Z 18:19:44.35  Creating a summary markdown file...
2017-10-13T16:19:44.3969783Z ##[error]18:19:44.35  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2017-10-13T16:19:44.4125201Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2017-10-13T16:19:44.4125201Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-10-13T16:19:44.4125201Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2017-10-13T16:19:44.4906463Z ##[debug]Calling InvokeGetRestMethod "/api/server/version" 
2017-10-13T16:19:44.5531455Z ##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.HostUrl = http://server/
2017-10-13T16:19:44.5843967Z ##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerUsername = ********
2017-10-13T16:19:44.5843967Z ##[debug]Variable read: MSBuild.SonarQube.ServerPassword = 
2017-10-13T16:19:44.6000209Z ##[debug]GET http://server/api/server/version with 0-byte payload
2017-10-13T16:19:44.6156456Z ##[debug]received 11-byte response of content type text/plain
2017-10-13T16:19:44.6937737Z Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish processing in order to determine the quality gate status.
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7250216Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 timeoutInMinutes)
2017-10-13T16:19:44.7406462Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

The installed sonarqube version is 6.5.0.27846, which also is the response of `/api/server/version`. The extension version is 3.0.2 and MSBuild for this build definition is set to 15.0 x86. Currently I'm running out of ideas to resolve this issue.

`run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.` Where can I add the -X switch? To add it at the prepare step in section `Additional Settings` will exit with `Unrecognized command line argument: -X`

Comment: What's the result if you analysis it through [SonarQube Scanner command](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) on build agent machine directly? Try to specify `/d:sonar.verbose=true` in Additional Settings for detail log.

Comment: What's the detail log after specifying /d:sonar.verbose=true?